# Why notifyItemChanged(position) not updating all the items in RecyclerView?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I am trying to update let's say 3 items simultaneously in recyclerview after fetching certain values from the firebase database. The below method iterates through ArrayList itemname thrice and with each value, it calls the method SecurityAlertSensor(itemname).

Within this method for each iteration, the respective item in recycler view shall change. Like if the **id** fetched from the SQLite DB is 1 then the 1st item of recycler view will be updated and on the next iteration, if the **id** is 2 then the 2nd item will be updated similarly for the 3rd item.

But with the below code only the last of the three items of the recycler view is updating the first two are not working.

```
for (int i=0; i<itemname.size(); i++) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            SecurityAlertSensor(itemname.get(i));
        }
        else if(!isOnline())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This method fetches the value from Firebase DB on each iteration and if the value is "1" then it calls notifyItemChanged(position) to update the specific item in recyclerview.

```
private void SecurityAlertSensor(final String email) {
        sec_ref2 = sec_ref1.child(email);
        sec_ref2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            int id;
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
             String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
             if (value != null)
             {
                 if (value.contains("0") || value.contains("1"))
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(Security.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     String[] tokens = value.split(",");
                     power_state = tokens[0];
                     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                     values.put(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.SEC_NAME_COL4, tokens[0]);
                     values.put(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.SEC_NAME_COL5, tokens[1]);
                     SecDB.update(SecurityDatabaseContract.UserDatabase2.TABLE_NAME2, values, "address='" + email + "'", null);

                     String query = "SELECT id FROM sec_table WHERE address='"+email+"'";
                     Cursor c1 = SecDB.rawQuery(query,null);

                     if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0)
                     {
                         while (c1.moveToNext()) {
                             id = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("id"));
                         }
                            c1.close();
                     }

                     if (tokens[1].equals("1")) {
                         alert_position = id;
                         userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(alert_position);
                     }
                 }
                 sec_ref2.removeEventListener(this);
             }
                else
                        Toast.makeText(Security.this, "Device Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  // Failed to read value
            }
        });
}
```

Inside the Recyclerview Adapter class onBindViewHolder method. This gets called each time the notifyItemChanged(position) is instantiated inside the main class.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserViewHolder holder, final int position) {
 if(position == Security.alert_position) {
            holder.state.setText("< Activated >");
            holder.state.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.cards.setBackgroundColor(0x33FF0000);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here in `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
if(position == Security.alert_position) {
```

You rely on the value of `Security.alert_position` being set to the item position on each iteration. I'm guessing that each call to `notifyItemChanged()` does not produce an immediate call to `onBindViewHolder()`, but that the calls made to `onBindViewHolder()` are asynchronous and happen later. By then `Security.alert_position` has already been set to the third value so that each time you enter `onBindViewHolder()`, the value of `Security.alert_position` is the last value that you set.

You could add some debug logging to verify my assumption. Generally your architecture is not good, as you are relying on the state stored in one place when doing something in another place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David. But why the same trick is working when fetching the same data from MySQL via Volley (All three items are updating properly)? Also, could you please suggest some workaround for this?

Comment: I don't know enough about how Volley works to answer that, sorry. Workaround? From the code you've posted I don't know enough about what you are trying to do here. Generally this architecture is wrong though.